# Are there any trophies that are impossible to acquire in next gen consoles on NG+?

Tags: achievements, the-witcher-3

I have a complete save in my PS4 that can be used in PS5. But with this save comes some doubts.

1. I already have all the potions, bombs and mutagens. Can I get the trophy for discovering recipes or creating stuff in new game+?
2. What about the other trophies that can relate to this? Are there any impossible to acquire trophies in the new game+?

Comment: Is the Witcher 3 considered a "new game" on your profile for the PS5 version? Like does it have its own trophies and such to earn (again)?

Comment: I think usually, a trophy got in PS4 will pop in PS5 if cross saves work. Like for instance, I got some achievements in Genshin Impact on PC, and next I opened it on my PS5 they all popped before I even logged in. But I think that is a 'common practice', needs to be programmed in and not something automatic, so Witcher could not do it.